# Can't use data assembly language

Tags: assembly

This code is to draw a line between (160, 60) to (480, 60)

```
data segment
    left DW 160
    right DW 480
data ends
code segment
   assume cs:code,ds:data
start:  mov ax,0012h  ;vga 640*480
        int  10h

        mov cx,160  ;start point
        mov dx,60
drawH1: mov al,0ah   ;color
        mov ah,0ch  ;draw       
        int 10h
        inc cx
        cmp cx,480 
        jng drawH1

        mov ah,0     ;Esc
        int 16h      
        cmp al,1bh   
        jz  exit     
 exit:  mov ax,0002h
        int 10h
        mov ah,4ch
        int 21h
code ends
end start
```

It works well. I defined left and right at beginning. But if I replace 160/480 by left/right. It will draw just one point. The reason seems to be `mov cx,160` is defferent from `mov cx,left`. But I don't actually know what's wrong. Some one can help me!?

Comment: Tag an assembler for more useful answers. Preliminary, I would say that you have to initialize your segment regs (`mov ax, @data`/`mov ds, ax` and so on). Furthermore some assembler consider `mov cx, left` as `mov cx, OFFSET left` others as `mov cx, WORD PTR [left]` (this should be your case). Finally, if you were to use the expression `left/right` anywhere in the code, beware that it won't perform the division of the values of the variables `left` and `right`, that would be impossible (such an expression must be available at assembly time). I will divide their offsets (if that's valid at all)

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the assembler that you use, your syntax must change to reference the memory offset vs the content.  For example:

```
mov cx, 160
```

This will almost universally move the immediate value 160 into the register.

```
width dw 160
...
mov cx, width
```

This might move the offset of *width* into `cx` or it might move the value stored at that location.  To be more clear, something like this would be best:

```
mov cx, offset width   ; some assemblers - Move the offset
mov cx, word ptr width ; some assemblers - Move content pointed to
mov cx, [width]        ; some assemblers - Move the content pointed to, size implied by register
```

More than likely, your assembler expects one of the last two.